# New Classes Turning Green After Creation(IntelliJ)

Tags: intellij-idea

Everytime I create a new class, the class name turns green(like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7zue.jpg)). All my old classes are still normal(light gray text color), and they look like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siTMg.jpg). I want my new classes to be light gray instead of light green. I installed Git to IntelliJ but I don't know if that affects it. Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: It's because of Git. Green is for added, but not commited files. Please check related article about colors: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-status-highlights.html

Comment: Oh okay, but is there a way to turn it off? Like the classes are gray instead of green?

Comment: You may remove Git support for your project in "File | Settings | Version Control"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing Git support for the project in "File | Settings | Version Control".

Credit to @y.bedrev

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Git makes the class green, for this you need to disconnect it from your project, this can be done like this:

**File | Settings | Version Control | Directory Mappings**

Then select none

Picture: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb5PQ.png)